# Pivoting For Multiple columns- Python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame likethis - .[image: req_1]

In which there are 3 columns and have some data, I want to PIVOT that DataFrame like below-[image: req_2]

If anyone can provide some idea on how to get resolve that it will be helpful.

Comment: not exactly unstack. I want all the 3 columns data in one column for a particular name.

Comment: `df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)`

Comment: Any Idea how we can add a column name in the newly created columns ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['A','B','C'], 'ColB': ['D','E','F' ],'ColC':['G','H','I'],'Name':['Rajish','Rohit','Rahim']})
print(df)
```

Result:

```
  ColA ColB ColC    Name
0    A    D    G  Rajish
1    B    E    H   Rohit
2    C    F    I   Rahim
```

Then do the transform:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['A','B','C'], 'ColB': ['D','E','F' ],'ColC':['G','H','I'],'Name':['Rajish','Rohit','Rahim']})
print(df)
```

Result:

```
df2 = (df.set_index(['Name'])
        .stack(dropna=False))
print(df2)
```